# with nvidia optimus, how do I tweak xorg.conf?

Tags: nvidia-optimus

My thinkpad P50 has nvidia optimus. 
When I run it in Intel-only mode, I get bad screen tearing. 
I can add a file to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf
which has this content:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "TearFree"    "true"
EndSection
```

However, when switching to intel

```
prime-select intel
```

no xorg.conf is written, and when going back to nvidia, this file prevents X from starting

So my attempt at adding tear free intel is worse than useless: it seems to do nothing when I want it to do something, and when I want it to do nothing, it breaks my system :(